# Find line break in formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I noticed that the `Contact.MailingStreet` field can be accessed line-by-line in reports with the `Mailing Address Line 1`, `Mailing Address Line 2`, and `Mailing Address Line 3` fields.

I want to create formula fields that are the equivalent of these fields, using the `FIND`, `LEFT`, `MID`, and `RIGHT` functions to break out the street address line by line.  I have tried various new line variations `(\n, \r\n, <br />)` but the `FIND` function doesnt seem to pick up on new lines.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just access the individual fields?

Comment: Mailing Address Line 1, 2, 3 only exist in reporting and are not actual fields.

Comment: Geez, i remember having this problem and I see I solved it with three custom fields: street_1__c, street_2__c, street_3__c and using a before insert/update trigger that transformed mailingStreet using a split('\n') into an array and then copying array[0] to street_1__c, array[1] to street_2__c and all remaining array elms to street_3__c

Comment: The trigger method is correct. Normal formula fields cannot see newlines (but validation rules can detect newlines via REGEX, which normal fields do not get access to).

Comment: Darn, not even FIND(BR(), MailingStreet) works, had a sneaky hope it might.

Comment: This is a Known Issue... Please follow the the link and let Salesforce know that it affects you! https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YkZAAU

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a Custom Setting, type Hierarchy. This setting needs to have a field in it that has the value:

```
a
b
```

In this answer, my custom setting is `Global__c` and my field is `CRLF__c`.

What characters you use doesn't matter, but the important thing is one character on the first line, and one character on the second line. The Length of this custom setting is actually 4 characters. Two printable, `a` and `b`, and two that don't have a glyph, `Carriage Return` aka `CR` aka `\r` and `Line Feed` aka `LF` aka `\n`.

`MID($Setup.Global__c.CRLF__c, 3, 1)` is now equivalent to a `Line Feed` character in the context of a formula. We can abuse this to do things like get the first line of an address field.

```
IF(
  CONTAINS(MailingStreet, MID($Setup.Global__c.CRLF__c,3,1)), 
  LEFT(
    MailingStreet, 
    FIND(MID($Setup.Global__c.CRLF__c,3,1), MailingStreet)
  ),
  MailingStreet
)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you,  thank you, thank you. What a cool solution. Here is my write up as to how I used your solution https://tdd.instawiki.com/display/SF/aiEasyLabel

Comment: This is a really clever solution. Just implemented it, with the slight variation of using a custom Label instead of a Custom Setting. That way, I can deploy the whole lot together.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something to the effect of:

```
String Line1, Line2, Line3;
String[] lines = addressFormula.split('\r\n');
Line1 = lines[0];
if (lines.size() > 1){
    Line2 = lines[1];
    if (lines.size() > 2){
        Line3 = lines[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this directly in a Salesforce Flow.
Create a text template variable of type plain text.
In the example it is called "text_T_baseForCRLF"
[image]
In the text template write the following:

```
-
-
```

Then create a formula with name e.g. name "form_T_CRLF" and with content:
[image]

```
SUBSTITUTE({!text_T_baseForCRLF}, "-", "")
```

Then you can use it in the flow.

In my case i needed to split a question and answer string inside a loop. So i  came opp with this formula to get the question part. Then there is another formula to get the answer after the line shift.

```
TRIM(
   MID({!LOOP_overAnswerGroups}, 
   FIND("Q.", {!LOOP_overAnswerGroups})+2, 
   FIND(form_T_CRLF, {!LOOP_overAnswerGroups})-4
   )
)
```