# Split Address Field into separate fields based on line-break

Tags: formula, formula-field, address

This an old and common question though

I need to split the Billing street based on line-break since it's a TextArea field value are entered on a separate line. `I need to split every line and store it in a separate field(Formula).`

Came Across many suggestions such as custom settings and custom labels but `client don't want to use custom settings or labels Is there a way to achieve it by only using the formula field`

[image]

```
field1= 525 S. Lexington Ave
field1= New Town Area
field1= West Gate
```

**Updated-** Achieved this using custom label For Row -1

```
IF( 
CONTAINS(BillingStreet, MID($Label.new_line,3,1)), 
 LEFT( 
 BillingStreet, 
 FIND(MID($Label.new_line,3,1), BillingStreet) 
 ), 
 BillingStreet                                                              
 )       //Returns 525 S. Lexington Ave
```

**Row -2 (Field2)**

```
IF(                                                   
CONTAINS(BillingStreet, MID($Label.new_line,3,1)),               
LEFT(                                                                   
    RIGHT(                                                     
     BillingStreet,                                       
     (LEN(BillingStreet) -(FIND(MID($Label.new_line,3,1),BillingStreet)))
     ), 
      FIND(MID($Label.new_line,3,1) , RIGHT(BillingStreet, LEN(BillingStreet) -FIND (MID($Label.new_line,3,1), BillingStreet)))-1 ),'')                 

     //Returns New Town Area
```

> Here I have used Label but Is there a way to do without label or
>   setting

Comment: you can see this link.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18909/find-line-break-in-formula-field.
Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: thanks @Gourav but still It need to be done without label or custom settings