# How to Identify Line Break in Text Area in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, address, textarea

In Flow, I need to break the default Street address field from the Account object, which is a text area field, that is part of the compound BillingAddress, into multiple strings by the line break, so that I can populate 2 street fields in another object.  Because it's a text area, the street address can appear on multiple lines.

For example convert this single string:

```
1 Main Street
Suite 1234
```

into multiple strings:

- 1 Main Street
- Suite 1234

I have tried to create a formula to do this, with no luck.  Here is  my attempt to get the first line:

```
IF(
    CONTAINS({!$Record.BillingStreet}, CHR(13)), 
    LEFT(
        {!$Record.BillingStreet}, 
        FIND(CHR(13), {!$Record.BillingStreet})
    ),
    {!$Record.BillingStreet}
)
```

I also tried searching for `CHR(13)` & `CHR(10)`

Searching for `BR()` does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution using this, at the bottom:  [Find line break in formula field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18909/find-line-break-in-formula-field)

After following that approach, here is the flow formula for getting the first line:

```
IF(
    CONTAINS({!$Record.BillingStreet}, {!form_T_CRLF}), 
    LEFT(
        {!$Record.BillingStreet}, 
        FIND({!form_T_CRLF}, {!$Record.BillingStreet})
    ),
    {!$Record.BillingStreet}
)
```